# Guestmount machine image inside Container running in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gitlab-ci

I am modifying a machine image(in the .img format) in a Gitlab pipeline. I have come across a strange quirk and I would like to know **why** this is happening.

**The runner**:

- Self-hosted Gitlab runner, using the docker+machine executor
- The executor is configured to run containers in privileged mode, with the `/dev/fuse` path mounted in the container, and the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability added to the job container.
- Job runs in `ubuntu:22.10` container

**The job**:
The job installs `libguestfs-tools` and `linux-image-generic`.

It downloads a raspberry pi machine image(2023-02-21-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img)

The image is then mounted: `guestmount -a 2023-02-21-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img -m /dev/sda2 -m /dev/sda1:/boot $CI_PROJECT_DIR/mnt-image`

Files get created in `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/mnt-image/boot/` as well as `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/mnt-image/lib/systemd/system/`

The image gets unmounted and the job completes: `guestunmount $CI_PROJECT_DIR/mnt-image`

**Question**:
With the job configured above, it works fine locally in a container using the same image. In the pipeline, the final image has the files created in `/boot`, but the ntfs partition is unmodified.

The really strange thing is that if, after unmounting the image, I re-mount and subsequently unmount then the final image has the files I created in the ntfs partition.

Why does this redundant step of a final mount+unmount produce the image I would expect?